# Click handler not attaching

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-mobile

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A4sqY/

Modified some code found here on SA for cloning search filters. Trying to add search filter blocks to a jQMobile app, code seems right not sure why it is only firing on the first instance, cannot seem to bind to dynamically created clones of search filters.

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="d" data-collapsed-icon="search" data-expanded-icon="search" class="ui-icon-nodisc" data-iconshadow="false">
    <h3>Search</h3>
        <form action="" id="search" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="js-selectblock">
                <div class="js-select">
                    <select name="select2[]" class="mySelect" >
                        <option value="1" selected="selected" > Search1</option>
                        <option value="2" >Search2</option>
                        <option value="3" >Search3</option>
                    </select> 
                    <span class="closeselect">X</span>
                </div>
                </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit">
                <div id="addmore">
                    Add another filter
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

The cloning acts as expected, it is the remove Filter that only binds to the initial one.

```
$(function(){
            $('#addmore').on('click', function(){
                if($('.closeselect').length < $('.js-select:first option').length) {
                    $('.js-selectblock > .js-select:first').clone().appendTo('.js-selectblock');   

                    $('.mySelect:not(:last) > option:selected').each(function () {
                        var disableOption = $(this).val();
                        $('.mySelect:last > option').each (function () {
                            if (disableOption === $(this).val()) {
                               $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');   
                            }                      
                        });
                    }); 
                    $('.mySelect:last > option:not(:disabled):first').attr('selected', 'selected');
                    disableSelectedOption();               
                }

                if($('.closeselect').length >= $('.js-select:first option').length) {
                    $('#addmore').hide();
                }  
            }); 
            $('.closeselect').on('click', function(){
                console.log('close click');
                // if($('.closeselect').length > 1) {
                //     console.log('close click');
                //     $(this).parent().remove(); 
                //     disableSelectedOption();
                //     $('#addmore').show();
                // }                   
            });
            $('.mySelect').on('change', function () {
                disableSelectedOption();
            });

            function disableSelectedOption() {
                $('.mySelect > option').each(function () {
                   $(this).removeAttr('disabled'); 
                });
                $('.mySelect > option:selected').each(function () {
                    var disableOption = $(this).val();
                    $('.mySelect > option:not(:selected)').each (function () {
                        if (disableOption === $(this).val()) {
                           $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');   
                        }                      
                    });
                });    
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use delegation for dynamic added content:

http://jsfiddle.net/A4sqY/1/

```
 $('form').on('click','.closeselect', function(){...});
 $('form').on('change','.mySelect', function () {...});
```

Comment: fiddle doesn't work... same results as original. Close 'X' doesn't remove the filter. Unless I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: What about uncommenting the part you have commented in your original jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/A4sqY/2/

Comment: So yeah, I was missing something obvious. Damnit. Works great, thank you very much. So that I understand, the delegation starts with the parent object (form), then applies the method to the element and runs the function?

Comment: You can find an explanation here: http://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/

Comment: as long as i know, you can bind events only to existing elements.

Comment: it's at time handler is read (the binding code) than the element have to be in the DOM, so yes, you can bind events only to existing elements.

Comment: @roasted, how hard is it to add functionality that increments each input's ID by 1 each time it is cloned? IE initial ID is "search" next one would be "search1"